# Prevent link dragging, but still allow text highlighting

Tags: javascript, html

I have some data in a table where clicking it will navigate you elsewhere, but people are requesting the ability to highlight the text to be able to copy/paste it elsewhere.  Since they are links, the default behavior in HTML is to drag the link... I don't know why or how that is useful, but I want to disable that on certain links.

**TL;DR**: I want to be able to highlight the text of a link **and** not drag it.

The gif below should help explain my issue.

### [image: Example]

#### The following methods are *NOT* what I want:

I have seen examples that **prevent both** highlighting & dragging using something like this

`<a draggable="false" href="#">`

or this

```
.no-drag {
  user-drag: none;
}
```

Or this

```
myElement.ondragstart = function () {
    return false;
};
```

But obviously that is not what I need here.Is what I want possible to do?

Comment: Btw you could consider a simple change to the UI; converting from `<a href="link">Text people want to select</a>` to `<span>Text people want to select</span><a href="link">Navigate</a>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@Julien Grégoire's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312305/79677) put me on the right track for this, but the below code is the basics of what I ended up using.

```js
var clickedEl = document.getElementById("test");
var limit = 5;
var mouseMoved = false;

function resetEvents() {
    clickedEl.onmousemove = null;
    clickedEl.ondragstart = null;
    clickedEl.onmouseleave = null;
    mouseMoved = false;
}

clickedEl.onmousedown = function (downEvent) {
    if (clickedEl.attributes.href) {
        clickedEl.onclick = function (clickEvent) {
            if (mouseMoved) {
                clickEvent.preventDefault();
            }
            resetEvents();
        };
    }
    
    clickedEl.onmouseleave = function () {
        resetEvents();
    };

    clickedEl.onmousemove = function (moveEvent) {
        // This prevents the text selection being dragged
        clickedEl.ondragstart = function (dragEvent) {
            dragEvent.preventDefault();
        };

        if (Math.abs(moveEvent.x - downEvent.x) >= limit || Math.abs(moveEvent.y - downEvent.y) >= limit) {
            // If user clicks then moves the mouse within a certain limit, select the text inside
            window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(clickedEl);
            mouseMoved = true;
        }
    };

};
```

```html
<a id="test" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click or select</a>
```

Answer (score 12):

In Google Chrome this works

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
```

Comment: Sadly, according to here https://caniuse.com/webkit-user-drag, this is not yet usable (Jan. 2022) on Firefox, IE11 or Chrome on Android.

Answer (score 7):

I'm super late to answer but I'm just gonna leave it here:

Just put `draggable="false"` inside `<a>` tag,

```
<a draggable="false" href="./"></a>
```

then in CSS you put:

```
body {
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply prevent the default `dragstart` behaviour

```js
const clickedEl = document.getElementById("test");
clickedEl.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault())
```

```html
<a id="test" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click or select</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could detect if user moves the mouse after the click and if so manage selection using `window.getSelection`. Something like this for example:

```js
var linkEl = document.getElementById('test')

linkEl.onmousedown = function(downEvent) {

  var clickedEl = downEvent.target;
  var mouseMoved = false;

  clickedEl.onmousemove = function() {

    // If user clicks then moves, select the whole link
    window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(clickedEl);

    // Set a flag to prevent opening the link
    mouseMoved = true;

    // Reset mousemove, else it'll run constantly
    clickedEl.onmousemove = null;

    // This is only to prevent having the text selection being dragged
    clickedEl.ondragstart = function(dragEvent) {
      dragEvent.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  if (mouseMoved) {
    // If mouse has moved, prevent default
    downEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<a draggable="false" id="test" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click or select</a>
```

Comment: This works great, except that it seems to always highlight the text regardless if I click or move the mouse

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution that worked for me. You can change '*' to 'a'.

```
*, *::after, *::before {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;    
}
```

Comment: Sadly, according to here https://caniuse.com/webkit-user-drag, this is not yet usable (Jan. 2022) on Firefox, IE11 or Chrome on Android.